# Firebase Auth - Disable a user and prevent him interacting with the backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If a user of my app performs some unwanted action, his account may be disabled by a moderator. **However, even if disabled, he will be able to use the app if he is already logged in. How can I prevent this?**

The code I use to disable a user is within a Cloud Functions and use the following:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    disabled: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling a user's account prevents them from signing in to the app in the future, and prevents their ID token from being refreshed. But their current ID token is still valid for up to an hour.

To detect the disabling of the user account, you can add their ID token to a blocklist and check against that list. You'd typically do that in your security rules, in your server-side code, and (for good measure) in the client. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [detecting ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation).